# jQuery datepicker date array disable dates incorrect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to disable dates returned from an array, problem is the disabled dates are not in the correct order, Jan's dates are showing in Feb, Feb's dates are showing in Mar and Mar are not showing at all as per image[image]

The code is below

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var bDates = [{ start: new Date(2019, 01, 06), end: new Date(2019, 01, 17) },
                            { start: new Date(2019, 02, 05), end: new Date(2019, 02, 07) },
                            { start: new Date(2019, 03, 07), end: new Date(2019, 03, 10) }];
        var dateFormat = 'yyyy mm dd',
            from = $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 3,
                    minDate:0,
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < bDates.length; i++) {
                            if (date >= bDates[i].start && date <= bDates[i].end) return [false, ''];
                        }
                        return [true, ''];
                    }
                })
                .on( "change", function() {
                    to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
                }),
            to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 3
                })
                .on( "change", function() {
                    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
                });


    } );
</script>
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing your dates wrong. See [Date constructor's parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters):

> The argument monthIndex is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and
>   December = 11.

Your code becomes (only changed the date constructors):

```js
$(function() {
  var bDates = [{
      start: new Date(2019, 0, 10),
      end: new Date(2019, 0, 17)
    },
    {
      start: new Date(2019, 1, 5),
      end: new Date(2019, 1, 7)
    },
    {
      start: new Date(2019, 2, 7),
      end: new Date(2019, 2, 10)
    }
  ];
  var dateFormat = 'yyyy mm dd',
    from = $("#from").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      minDate: 0,
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < bDates.length; i++) {
          if (date >= bDates[i].start && date <= bDates[i].end) return [false, ''];
        }
        return [true, ''];
      }
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#to").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
<input id="from" />
<input id="to" />
```

Comment: Hi Jeto, I'm an idiot, I forgot all about that. Thanks

Comment: No problem, happens. That's a bit counter-intuitive, to be fair :)